# Polybrush mesh is not rendered on Android

Tags: unity-game-engine

Polybrush mesh works fine in Unity editor but not visible on Android.  I've tried to add Polybrush shaders to *Always included shaders* in *Project Settings/Graphics* but it doesn't work. What could be the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is solved.** I created a custom *Unlit* shader and used it instead of Polybrush *Standard Texture Blend Bump* and it worked.